# Implicit function's condition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Hey anyone can help me with this problem? My friend asked me to find the implicit function of this:

$$(x+2y)\,dx - 2xy\,dy = 0 \qquad\text{(1)}$$

My approach is to use a function $u(x,y)$ then $du = u_x \, dx + u_y \, dy$. Then with (1) I have $u_x = x+2y$ and $u_y = -2xy$ (2).  But then I can't find the function u which satisfied the condition (2).  So I wonder are there any conditions for the implicit function? And how should I deal with (1)?

Comment: Do you mean a potential function?

Comment: @bharb No my approach is to find a Multivariable function u(x,y) which satisfied the condition (1).

Answer (score 1):

The differential form
$$(x+2y) dx +2xy dy$$
is not closed, hence the differential form cannot be exact. In fact
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (x+2y)=2$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2xy)=2y$$
More explicitly, if a potential function $u$ existed then
$$u_x=x+2y \implies u=\frac 12 x^2+2xy+C_1(y)$$
and 
$$u_y=2xy \implies u=xy^2+C_2(x)$$
The two conditions are clearly not compatible.

Comment: That's what I think of too. So are there another way to deal with this? Or it is cannot be solved?

Comment: @P-Man108 No, such a function cannot exist.